# is it possible to take low resolution image from street camera, increase it and see image details

Tags: image-processing

I would like to know if it is possible to take low resolution image from street camera, increase it
and see image details (for example a face, or car plate number). Is there any software that is able to do it?
Thank you.

example of image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMTkn.jpg

Comment: don't believe what you see in movies...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible? Yes. In existence? not to my knowledge.

What you are referring to is called [super-resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superresolution). The way it works, in theory, is that you combine multiple low resolution images, and then combine them to create a high-resolution image.

The way this works is that you essentially map each image onto all the others to form a stack, where the target portion of the image is all the same. This gets ***extremely complicated extremely fast*** as any distortion (e.g. movement of the target) will cause the images to differ dramatically, on the pixel level.

But, let's you have the images stacked and have removed the non-relevant pixels from the stack of images. You are left hopefully with a movie/stack of images that all show the exact same image, but with sub-pixel distortions. A sub-pixel distortion simply means that the target has moved somewhere inside the pixel, or has moved partially into the neighboring pixel.

You can't measure if the target has moved within the pixel, but you can detect if the target has moved partially into a neighboring pixel. You can do this by knowing that the target is going to give off X amount of photons, so if you see 1/4 of the photons in one pixel and 3/4 of the photons in the neighboring pixel you know it's approximate location, which is 3/4 in one pixel and 1/4 in the other. You then construct an image that has a resolution of these sub-pixels and place these sub-pixels in their proper place.

All of this gets very computationally intensive, and sometimes the images are just too low-resolution and have too much distortion from image to image to even create a meaningful stack of images. I did read a paper about a lab in a university being able to create high-resolution images form low-resolution images, but it was a very very tightly controlled experiment, where they moved the target *precisely* X amount from image to image and had a very precise camera (probably scientific grade, which is far more sensitive than any commercial grade security camera).

In essence to do this in the real world reliably you need to set up cameras in a very precise way and they need to be very accurate in a particular way, which is going to be expensive, so you are better off just putting in a better camera than relying on this very imprecise technique.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is possible to do super-resolution (SR) out of even a single low-resolution (LR) image! So you don't have to hassle taking many LR images with sub-pixel shifts to achieve that. The intuition behind such techniques is that natural scenes are full of many repettitive patterns that can be use to enahance the frequency content of similar patches (e.g. you can implement dictionary learning in your SR reconstruction technique to generate the high-resolution version). Sure the enhancment may not be as good as using many LR images but such technique is simpler and more practicle.

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop would be your best bet.  But know that you cannot reliably inclrease the size of an image without making the quality even worse.